# Vim plugin/script to automatically list used functions in comment under #include

Tags: c, vim, ctags

Coming back to C after some time away in other languages, I found myself mimicking the style of explicitly listing what I was using from each `#include` at the top of each `.c` file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>/*{{{
  * free()
}}}*/
#include <unistd.h>/*{{{
  * pipe()
}}}*/
#include <string.h>/*{{{
  * strcmp()
  * strstr()
}}}*/
#include<stdio.h>/*{{{
  FILE
  * fdopen()
  * fclose()
}}}*/
// ...
```

To an experienced C programmer, or one used to using `ctags` or some IDE, figuring out where each of the functions I'm using may be easy, but for a lot of the people I work with, C is not their best language. And I know having such annotations when I was less experienced would have helped me.

However, keeping such comments up-to-date is a PITA, and prone to mistakes (leaving something in after I stop using it, forgetting to insert something when I do).

Is there an existing plugin or script for vim that does this (or something like this) for me?

I've got an idea of how I would do it:

- run through each identifier in the file
- check the `taglist()` entries
- see if any's file match an existing `#include` statment
- insert comment under the import

And I've written vimscript before, I just want to avoid recreating the wheel.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/include-what-you-use/ does something like this, but it is a pain to run it on code that wasn't written with IWYU in mind as 1) it won't like your project structure and 2) it will refactor the includes to something it prefers.

Comment: why on earth would someone want to do that?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such beast yet. I can add a missing `#include` from the identifier under the cursor, or fetch the namespace the id belongs to in order to prepend the id with the namespace, but not what you're looking for.  
Using instead IWYU to just clean what you don't need is a nice alternative I think.

Comment: Luc Hermitte: what do you use to add a missing `#include`?